# Re-implementation of strptime in C++11 leads to strange behavior with VisualStudio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, datetime, c++11, gcc

In order to have a fully portable code Win/Linux,
I tried to re-implement a *strptime* like function using C++11 and all the hints I found on *stackoverflow* (and others).
But I see a strange behaviors (particularly with VisualStudio).
Here is the code :

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstring>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std ;

//-- my function ----------------------------------------------------------------------

time_t my_strptime ( string date , const char * format )
    {
    try {
        tm t ;
        memset( &t,0,sizeof( t )) ;
        istringstream ss( date ) ;
        ss.imbue( locale( setlocale( LC_ALL,0 )));
        ss >> get_time( &t,format ) ;
        if (!ss.fail()) return mktime( &t ) ;
        }
    catch ( ... ) {}
    return time_t(-1) ;
    }

//-- and now some tests ---------------------------------------------------------------

#include <iostream>

void test ( string date , const char * fmt )
    {
    time_t t = my_strptime( date,fmt ) ;
    cout << date << " -> " << t ;
    if (t >= 0) cout << " -> " << put_time( localtime( &t ),fmt ) ;
    cout << endl ;
    }

int main ( int , const char ** )
    {
    const char * fmt = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" ;
    test("2023-01-25 12:34:56",fmt ) ;
    test("2023-01-25 12:34"   ,fmt ) ;
    test("2023-01-25 12:34:"  ,fmt ) ;
    cout << "done." << endl ;
    }
```

And here are the outputs :
With Linux / gcc :

```
2023-01-25 12:34:56 -> 1674646496 -> 2023-01-25 12:34:56
2023-01-25 12:34: -> -1
2023-01-25 12:34 -> 1674646440 -> 2023-01-25 12:34:00
done.
```

With Windows / mingw's gcc :

```
2023-01-25 12:34:56 -> 1674642896 -> 2023-01-25 11:34:56
2023-01-25 12:34: -> -1
2023-01-25 12:34 -> 1674646440 -> 2023-01-25 12:34:00
done.
```

With Windows / Visual Studio 2017 in Release :

```
2023-01-25 12:34:56 -> 1674642896 -> 2023-01-25 11:34:56
2023-01-25 12:34: -> -1
2023-01-25 12:34 -> 1674646440 -> 2023-01-25 12:34:00
done.
```

With Windows / Visual Studio 2017 in Debug :

```
2023-01-25 12:34:56 -> 1674646496 -> 2023-01-25 12:34:56
2023-01-25 12:34: -> -1
```

During the third test it crashes and pops up a dialog box with
**Debug Assertion Failed!

Expression: istreambug_iterator is not dereferencable**
(even the *try/catch* doesn't prevent the crash)

Is there a way to implement *my_strptime* in such a way it doesn't crash with VisualStudio+debug ?
By the way, the third test should always return -1, since the input string does not match the format...

Comment: An assertion doesn't throw an error, so you *can't* catch it.

Comment: That assertion failed in Visual Studio lets you click "Retry" to debug the code. I'd suggest that, and seeing what the problem actually is. VS in debug mode adds in a ton of error checking to help you find errors in your code, it doesn't usually introduce errors (though, it does happen on occasion). Running your code though, in VS 2022, I get no assertions failing.

Comment: Thank you @ChrisMM, but the input string is coming from a given file, that I can't amend. So when a date doesn't match the format, I just want to get some kind of *false* return, not a popup that I must manually close...

Comment: That assertion that it's trying to dereference an istream iterator in such a way is undefined behaviour, which tends to mean it's a problem with your code. Now, if it works with the given code, but not the input file, then it might be an issue with how you're reading the file. If you consistently get that assertion failure with the above code in VS, I honestly don't see anything wrong with it, and VS2022 does not have the issue, so it **might** be an issue with the older compiller.

Comment: Have you tried the latest Visual Studio 2022?

Comment: Thanx @MinxinYu-MSFT, it seems to be a known issue in VS2017. See [https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/c-stdget-time-not-parsing-correctly/140618]. But for now, I'm stuck with this version...